# Shortest Path via multiple points [C++]

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

Given a grid in which the content of each cell can be

**X**: a "wall"

**H**: a "checkpoint" (at most 5 of them)

**G**: the starting position (exactly one)

I have to find the minimum number of moves required to cover all checkpoints (**H**) starting from **G**.  Individual moves can be horizontal or vertical, though diagonal movement can be achieved by combining horizontal and vertical moves.  Moves out of the grid or to walls (**X**) are not possible.
 
For the grid

```
    ..H..
    ..X.H
    G...X
```

the expected answer is **7**.

The number of rows and columns in the grid can be at most 20.

I tried writing bfs code to solve the problem, but when tested with the grid above it produces **6**, which is incorrect.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  Could someone please help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include &lt;bits/stdc++.h>
#include &lt;algorithm>
#include &lt;cstdio>
#include &lt;stdlib.h>
#include &lt;cmath>
#include &lt;cstring>
#include &lt;math.h>
#include &lt;string>
#include &lt;sstream>
#include &lt;vector>
#include &lt;iomanip>
#include &lt;deque>
#include &lt;queue>

#define loop(i, n) for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
#define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0' < (_=getchar());x=(x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)  
#define ull unsigned long long  

char _;

using namespace std;
typedef pair <int, int> ipair;

int rows, columns, startx, starty, hiders;

char grid[20][20];
char buffer[255];

bool valid(int x, int y){  
    if(x >= 0 && x < rows && y >= 0 && y < columns && grid[x][y] != 'X')  
        return true;  
    return false;  
}  

int main(){  
    scanf("%i%i%i", &rows, &columns, &hiders);  

    //this is where I set up the grid, at put it in the grid array.  

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){  
        scanf("%s", &buffer);  
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){  
            if(buffer[j] == 'G'){  
                startx = i;  
                starty = j;  
            }  
            grid[i][j] = buffer[j];  
        }  
    }  

    queue<ipair> Q; //keeps track of positions  
    queue<int> DQ; //keeps track of distance  
    int found = 0; //how many checkpoints are found  

    Q.push(make_pair(startx, starty)); //push start pos  
    DQ.push(0);  

    while(!Q.empty()){  
        int x = Q.front().first; //check x  
        int y = Q.front().second; //check y  

        if(found == hiders){ //if we found the amount needed  
            printf("%i", DQ.front()); // print current distance  
            return 0;  
        }  

        if(grid[x][y] == 'H'){ //found checkpoint  
            found++; //found a hider  
        }  
        //if it's possible to move right  
        if(valid(x + 1, y)){  
            Q.push(make_pair(x+1, y));  
            DQ.push(DQ.front() + 1);  
        }  
        //if it's possible to move left  
        if(valid(x - 1, y)){  
            Q.push(make_pair(x-1, y));  
            DQ.push(DQ.front() + 1);  
        }  
        //if it's possible to move up  
        if(valid(x, y + 1)){  
            Q.push(make_pair(x, y + 1));  
            DQ.push(DQ.front() + 1);  
        }  
        //if it's possible to move down  
        if(valid(x, y - 1)){  
            Q.push(make_pair(x, y - 1));  
            DQ.push(DQ.front() + 1);  
        }  

        Q.pop();  
        DQ.pop();  
        grid[x][y] = 'X'; //set the current coordinates as visited/walls  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I guess you will better off by asking this question on a programming interview/competition QA website. But for the case to maximize your chances to obtain an answer, please at least give an example of input and its expected correct output.

Comment: We can't easily tell what's going wrong either, so can you please tell us? Do you have build problems? Runtime crashes? Wrong or unexpected output? Please give us more details, and if possible try to narrow it down yourself by running in a debugger and stepping through the code, line by line if necessary.

Comment: updated the code, and added comments. My problem is that I'm getting wrong numbers.

Comment: do you need the shortest path so that all check points are covered ?

Comment: I am still unclear about problem statement can you elaborate ?

Comment: @sasha We are given a grid, we must traverse it and find the shortest distance so that every checkpoint (labeled 'H') has been visited.

Comment: @BorisMediaProds But it might be possible that all checkpoints could not be reached in that case do you need to cover maximum number of checkpoints that can be reached in shortest path, if so I would suggest updating your problem statement accordingly

Comment: @sasha It is guaranteed that a valid path exists.

Comment: yeah sorry about that thought X were checkpoints, one last clarification what can be the maximum size of grid , number of checkpoints ?

Comment: Btw, it's illegal to name grobal variable `_`.

Comment: @sasha the maximum grid size is 20x20, and the maximum amount of checkpoints is 5.

Comment: @BorisMediaProds For sure you can't   solve the question just by bfs ( bfs + bitmask is required ) but why your code gives 6 that is a different question

Comment: problem statement said, recursion could be required. But I do not know how to implement recursion nor bitmask

Comment: the basic mistake in your approach is that when you have found the last checkpoint and all checkpoints are covered it is not necessary all those checkpoints were covered in the path from G to the last checkpoint you cover. And I am sorry but you would have to learn recursion/bitmask on your own and if you have doubt in that you can post it as a new question :)

Comment: what i'm trying to do is this. When a check point is found from G, run a new BFS from that position to any other checkpoint. Do you have an idea on how I could implement that in my solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69690/discussion-between-sasha-and-borismediaprods).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem solvable by BFS.

At a first glance Branch and Bound or Dynamic is the way to go.

B&B will definitely get you there, but it's hard to implement and It's slower than Dynamic.

The first Dynamic that pops into mind will require 5 20x20 grids , but I'm not 100% sure of it (it's a first sight feedback).